# how to handle firebase's asynchronous snapshot.val() function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

From what I understand, Firebase's `snapshot.val()` function is asynchronous, but I am not sure how to handle/change my code to account for this situation.

In short, this is the code of my controller:

```
 .controller('MyController', ['$firebase', '$scope', 'authService', 'rootRef', function(authService, $firebase, $scope, rootRef) {

    var auth = authService.getCurrentUser();
    $scope.data = [];

    if (auth) {
      rootRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());

        $scope.data.push(snapshot.val());
        console.log($scope.data);
      })

    };
```

From this code, what I see in the console is this:

> > output of snapshot.val()
> >     output of $scope.data

However, the code in between `console.log(snapshot.val())` and `console.log($scope.data)` does NOT seem to run because my $scope.data variable **does not get updated**!

Can someone please explain this behavior?

I think it has to do with the fact that `snapshot.val()` is asynchronous. But more importantly, can someone explain how I can easily resolve this issue instead of doing what I figured out below.

My solution:

I figured out one way to make it work, which is VERY roundabout. What I do is I take `snapshot.name()`, which gives me the `$id` or key for this object. I then make a `.$asObject().$loaded()` call to the location with that `$id` (essentially getting a promise to read that precise object). Then, in the success callback, I update `$scope.data`.

Comment: have you tried $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: Getting a snapshot from a ref is asynchronous. But subsequently calling `snapshot.val()` is **synchronous**, you get the result immediately.

Comment: Your solution indeed sounds highly convoluted. Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You defined an array called "data" on scope:

```
$scope.data = [];
```

But you are pushing to a variable called "testing" in your onComplete callback

```
$scope.testing.push(snapshot.val());
```

Comment: sorry, i wish it were that easy. that was just a typo from when i tried to change my variables so it wasn't so confusing. i'll fix it now.

Comment: While you are at it, you might want to fix the order of your injections.

 ['$firebase', '$scope', 'authService', 'rootRef', function(authService, $firebase, $scope, rootRef) { ... }]

Comment: And let us know what you are actually doing to get the child_added event to fire and what snapshot.val() and $scope.data evaluate to at the time of you console.log statements.